# Admin Access for Webform Entries

Tags: webforms

The following problem has occurred: 
A client fills in a reservation form, but the time requested is already fully booked. The clerk and the client negotiate a different time, and the clerk wants to change the requested time (f.e. 18:00) to the negotiated time (f.e. 20:00) -- but as the same form has a date restriction (one cannot reserve on the same day) the clerk can't save the form at the day of the appearance.

Is there any way to give a role the permission to change every webform, without any restrictions? I.e. any changes made by role "Trusted User" will not be checked in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Webform for Drupal 8 allows you to give a role (or specific user) access to view and update submissions of a SPECIFIC webform to accomplish what you need

Goto **Settings > Access** of the webform in question and assign **VIEW ANY SUBMISSIONS** and  **UPDATE ANY SUBMISSIONS** to your **Trusted user** role

[image]

Than you have to give this user the URL to view and edit/update all the submissions.  For example for the contact form they should visit `/admin/structure/webform/manage/CONTACT/results/submissions` and they would be able to see all submissions and edit them.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. The field restriction still get checked, even for the Admin / SuperUser with all access rights. The form you showed is just a "by form" override of the system wide webform access rights, and is in no way different to these. Been there, did that drill, no avail. But still thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @NorbertFürst I have actually tested what I posted and it works I am not sure what might be different in your installation, so you might want to try posting more detail or perhaps try it on a clean install.